# How would a regular expression that matches sentences while ignoring tag content look like?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to wrap single sentences of a given text with span-tags which is working pretty good so far.

`$this.html().replace(/\b.*?[\.\?\!]/gi, "<span>$&<\/span>");`

Now, there are some other span- and b-tags already mixed up in the content like this:

`Gumbo groundnut daikon radicchio scallion lettuce rock melon peanut. <span class="yellow">Catsear swiss chard epazote bush tomato peanut chicory amaranth tomato gourd.</span> Earthnut pea brussels sprout gumbo celery tomato salad kale. Spinach scallion tomatillo bitterleaf lentil <b>green</b> bean celery amaranth onion catsear sweet pepper fava bean silver beet spinach.`

Since I don't want to get rid of those tags and I don't want to encapsulate them either the solution could be to:

1. just ignore tags and what is inside
2. treat tags as sentence endings and beginnings

So in the end it would kind of look like this:

`<span>Gumbo groundnut daikon radicchio scallion lettuce rock melon peanut. <span class="yellow">Catsear swiss chard epazote bush tomato peanut chicory amaranth tomato gourd.</span> <span>Earthnut pea brussels sprout gumbo celery tomato salad kale.</span> <span>Spinach scallion tomatillo bitterleaf lentil </span><b>green</b><span> bean celery amaranth onion catsear sweet pepper fava bean silver beet spinach.</span>`

What would such a regular expression look like?
I am getting quite a headache over this, since my regex-skills are quite limited yet.

Comment: It would look like an XML parser, not a regex.

Comment: _"...Now you have two problems..."_

Comment: Instead of taking the html just take the text `$this.text()`

Comment: using `$this.text()` would remove those inner tags and I'd like to keep them

Answer (score 1):

Write a parser, not a regular expression. It will be very hard to deal with nested HTML-tags for instance with just regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I have now implemented a little function that does more or less what I wanted. It basically replaces all children (spans,bs,etc.) with placeholder-elements so they won't mess with the regular expression. Later I just replace the placeholders with the original child-elements. It is kind of a quick and dirty solution, but for now it works well enough.

```
function wrapSentences($element){
var j = 0, i = 0, placeholders = [];

 $.each($element.children(),function(){
     var p = $("<b id='p"+j+"'></b>");
     $(this).after(p).remove();
       placeholders.push($(this));
    j++;                              
 });

 $element.html($element.html().replace(/\(?[A-Z][^\.]+[\.!\?]\)?/g, "<span class='s'>$&<\/span>"));


 $.each(placeholders,function(){
       $element.find("#p"+i).replaceWith(this);
      i++;
 });
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lebushi/UGBPy/5/)